# Remote desktop aborts copy when copying text to clipboard

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, clipboard

When I copy a file from Windows Remote Desktop to my local machine, if I click on Ctrl-C (copy to clipboard) or copy to clipboard with mouse, the file copy aborts!

The message box says "Error Copying File or Folder" and "Unspecified error":

[image]

The file is large and I can't restrain myself from copying to clipboard for so long :)

Any fix to this problem or other recommended workaround?

Comment: Found related - https://superuser.com/questions/1290207/ctrlc-on-local-machine-terminates-the-file-copy-being-done-on-rdp-connection

Comment: This is not a bug - on Windows Ctrl+C is supposed to stop the current operation. Please tell how you are copying the file and the text, whether in the RDP session or on the client computer, to see if we can come up with a workaround.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 though and this still happens.

Comment: @sashoalm: Please give an *exact description* of what you are doing.

Comment: I am transferring a file in Remote Desktop, and when I click Ctrl+C, the transfer aborts with a message box saying "Error Copying File or Folder".

Comment: I'm copying from a remote machine running Windows Server 2016 to my own machine which is running Windows 10.

Comment: @sashoalm: Which window has the focus when doing CTRL-C?

Comment: @sashoalm... How large is the file and is it an exe or of a type which can be executed, what AV software are you running? It is a large file size wise of 2 GB or more? Have you considered using RDP [drive redirection](https://i.imgur.com/kzxkAJc.png) rather than copy and pasting across the RDP sessions? This way once you RDP into the machine you need to have the file copied to, you go to file explorer and navigate the drive(s) you redirect from there—I just showed simple "C" drive example here https://i.imgur.com/8QikQoY.png. Let me know if you like this solution so I can write it up for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a known limitation to MSTSC and there is no workaround that I know of (except using some other remoting / file sharing solution - e.g.: OneDrive, Dropbox etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You can get around this problem by using 7-zip or any other compression utilities that can create archives with volumes. For example you can compress a large file into a number of 10MB (or smaller) volumes. If the download is disrupted at least you have the already downloaded volumes. You will have to copy the rest again until all is transferred. When you have all volumes downloaded just un-compress the volumes and the original large file should be restored.
Regards,
John Zatyko